# loop through request body node js + express

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, express

Im sending a request with data as an array of objects:

```
 [
  {id: "1"},
  {id: "2"},
  {id: "3"}
 ]
```

im using `JSON.stringify()` and my req.body looks like this:
`{ '{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}': '' }`

Now i want to loop through req.body and get all the ids so i can delete them from the SQL DB.
Im using Sequelize.
The back end:

```
exports.deleteIds = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body)
//here should be loop so i can delete all the ids one by one.
    Model.destroy({
        where: {
            id: 
        }
    })
}
```

The post request (client):

```
let ids = []
//maybe here is the problem?
for (var i = 0; i < selectedRow.length; i++) {
   ids.push({id:selectedData[i].id})          
}

let Url = "/admin/deleteIds"
let data = JSON.stringify(ids)

event.preventDefault();

$.post(Url, data, function (data, status) {

  }).done(function (res) {
     if (res.ids.length == 0) {
        $('#mainContent').html('<h1>0 users found</h1>')
     }
  })
  .fail(function (err) {
    console.log(err.responseJSON.message)
  })
```

Comment: which db library are you using?, it might be a built it option

Comment: @Itamar im using Sequelize

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT

We we do is all even easier, by sending and array of ids and using it in the server directly.

Client:

```js
let ids = []
for (var i = 0; i < selectedRow.length; i++) {
   ids.push(selectedData[i].id)  // <-- this is the change         
}

let Url = "/admin/deleteIds"
let data = {items: ids}
//...
```

Server:

```js
exports.deleteIds = (req, res, next) => {
   const ids = req.body.items; // <-- no mapping needed
   Model.destroy({
      where: {id: ids}
   })
}
```

---

POST calls body should be a valid JSON, which means that it should be an js object.

Assuming you use Fetch

Sending data to server with Fetch API

```js
 const rawResponse = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({items:  [ {id: "1"}, {id: "2"}, {id: "3"} ]})
  });
```

First, if you get the req.body as an object, there is no reason to use `JSON.stringify`. if not use `JSON.parse` or [Express's body-parser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html)

Second you probably have a way in the DB library to send multiple IDs to destroy.

If you use Sequelize.js for example:

```js
exports.deleteIds = (req, res, next) => {
   const ids = req.body.items.map(({id}) => id); 
   Model.destroy({
      where: {id: ids}
   })
}
```

In case this option does not exist, lets loop:

```js
exports.deleteIds = (req, res, next) => {
   req.body.items.forEach(({id}) => {
      Model.destroy({
        where: {id}
      })
  }) 
}
```

Your fixed POST call:

```js
let ids = []
for (var i = 0; i < selectedRow.length; i++) {
   ids.push({id:selectedData[i].id})          
}

let Url = "/admin/deleteIds"
let data = {items: ids} // <-- this is the change

event.preventDefault();

$.post(Url, data, function (data, status) {

  }).done(function (res) {
     if (res.ids.length == 0) {
        $('#mainContent').html('<h1>0 users found</h1>')
     }
  })
  .fail(function (err) {
    console.log(err.responseJSON.message)
  })
```

Comment: Im using body parser as a middleware already. when im trying to send the post request with the array of object without JSON.stringify ```[  {id: "1"},  {id: "2"},  {id: "3"}]``` ,im getting ```{ undefined: [ '', '', '' ] }``` (when console.log req.body)

Comment: can you add to the question the client  post call and post server handler?

Comment: post Fetch api post example

Comment: I added the post request

Comment: Thank you, i will try it, so just to make sure i can change my code this line so i will have the same code like you to get valid json data```let data = JSON.stringify({items: ids})```

Comment: Yes, added you're code fixed in the answer at the bottom.
if it works, please mark as answer for future users

Comment: added an edit at the top with an even simpler implementation :)

Comment: I tried all the three solutions, it doesn't work, req.body.items is undefined. i even tried to post it hardcoded ```JSON.stringify({items:  [ {id: "1"}, {id: "2"}, {id: "3"} ]})``` and items is undefined. Toda raba for helping, im more than an hour on this issue

Comment: I did the solution on the top. but i changed one thing and its working perfect. i post the data  without JSON.stringify: ```{items:  [ {id: "1"}, {id: "2"}, {id: "3"} ]}``` and its working

Comment: Happy I could help

Comment: edit your answer and delete the JSON.stringify from the solution. i choose to do it with ```const ids = req.body.items.map(({id}) => id); ``` and its working good thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As another user mentions, req.body should always be valid json, so receiving an array is unlikely.

When you receive a valid json request, in Sequelize you can use three methods:

1. A `get()` function that determines what you retrieve from the database: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getters-setters-virtuals.html
2. A `set()` method on the model that runs a function on what you want to save to the database:

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: DataTypes.STRING,
  password: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    set(value) {
      this.setDataValue('password', hash(value));
    }
  }
});
```

3. (Probably my recommendation here) A function directly on the controller, like in this example where I slugify an organization name:

```
  try {
    const result = await Organization.create({
      name: req.body.name,
      type: req.body.type,
      slug: slugify(req.body.name, { lower: true, remove: /[*+~.()'"!:@]/g, strict: true }),
      fields: allowedFields
    }) catch(err) { etc.}
```

Comment: Object keys would not work as it's was an array in the question

Comment: Sorry Itamar, I missed that. Will update. The create function I suggest is just an example on how to use the inline Model controller function possibility in Sequelize